# DependencyProperty how to?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What is my problem? It do not work
(mvvm)

I get empty textbox and when I change textbox text OnCurrentReadingChanged is not called

```
namespace Test
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new BaseModel();      
        this.InitializeComponent();           
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ImgPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImgPosition", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow),
     new PropertyMetadata("ddd", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCurrentReadingChanged)));

    private static void OnCurrentReadingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
  }
}

<Window xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Test">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox Margin="141,81,254,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding View:MainWindow.ImgPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the issue here? Is it like you are not able to get the depenedency property in XAML?

Comment: @jadavparesh06, yes, I get empty textbox and when I change textbox text OnCurrentReadingChanged is not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding to a `DependencyProperty` on the `MainWindow` not your `DataContext` you can use 'FindAncestor' binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ImgPosition, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type View:MainWindow}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: but what about this? <Setter Property="View:TunnelDisplay.ImgPosition" Value="1"/>